# Como generar factura con Report viewer, SQL SERVER y C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, report

Tengo el diseño de la factura creado.
Tengo el procedimiento almacenado hecho.

Solo me falta saber como pasar el parámetro para que cuando abra la factura cargue los datos correspondientes.

Me explico:

tengo un formulario de ventas el cual genera un código de venta cada vez que realizo una y ese código es el que solicita mi procedimiento almacenado como parámetro, quisiera saber como hago para que al cargar el formulario que contiene el reporte se pase el código de la venta como parámetro.

Detallo todo:

```
    if (MessageBox.Show("¿Desea imprimir la factura?", "Samuel Droid", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
     {
         FacturadeVenta frm = new FacturadeVenta();
         frm.txtidventa.Text = lblidventa.Text;
         frm.ShowDialog();   
     }
```

Así le paso el código que necesito al formulario que contiene el reporte y lo recibe correctamente, solo necesito saber como hacer para que el reporte lea ese dato y lo asimile como parámetro para que cargue los datos correspondientes de la factura generada?

Este es el procedimiento:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_FACTURAVENTA] @IDVENTA INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT ventas.IDVenta
        ,ventas.Identificacion
        ,clientes.Nombres
        ,clientes.Apellidos
        ,ventas.ID
        ,productos.Producto
        ,productos.Marca
        ,productos.Modelo
        ,productos.Descripcion
        ,ventas.Cantidad
        ,productos.PrecioVenta
        ,ventas.Subtotal
        ,ventas.ITBIS
        ,ventas.Total
        ,ventas.Fecha
    FROM Tab_ventas AS ventas
    INNER JOIN Tab_productos AS productos ON ventas.ID = productos.ID
    INNER JOIN Tab_clientes AS clientes ON ventas.Identificacion = clientes.Identificacion
    WHERE IDVenta = @IDVENTA
END
```

Comment: como llamas al store ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el diseño del Reporte hay algo llamado parámetros [@Parameters] solo necesitas definir dichos parametros y enviarlos con `ReportParameters` (En caso de String, Int, Etc) 
para cargar una grilla en el reporte, utiliza el origen de datos (Dataset) del reporte.
 Te dejo unos ejemplos abajo de un proyecto que hice con Sql, C# y que imprime usando Reportviewer

```
  /*Defino mis cadenas a enviar */
                string p1 = lbl_Nombre.Text; // Nombre Cliente
                string p2 = lbl_Identificacion.Text; //Identificacion Cliente
                string p3 = NombreAlmacen.Text; // Nombre Almacen


 ReportDataSource origenDatos = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dataGridView1.DataSource); //Así cargas valores a una "Table" en el reporte (si es que lo tiene)

        Visor.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(origenDatos); //Agregas al reporte (Visor es el nombre de mi ReportViewer)



        ReportParameter[] parametros = new ReportParameter[12]; //Así defines los parámetros a enviar al reporte (Dentro de "[]" defines la cantidad de paramaatros)
        parametros[0] = new ReportParameter("NombreCliente", p1);
        parametros[1] = new ReportParameter("CC", p2);
```

etc...

```
Visor.LocalReport.SetParameters(parametros);  //Aquí envías los parámetros al reporte

        Visor.RefreshReport(); // No te Olvides de Refrescar C;
```